# Read the different element value in CDATA

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

```xml
<![CDATA[BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
FN:D Formatted Name
N:D Surname;D Given name;D Additional names;D Name prefix;D Name Suffix
ORG:D Organization Unit;D Org Unit
END:VCARD
]]>
```

How can I read all the values which are present in this CDATA and store them in separate variables  like FN: value, N: value?

Comment: Write or find a VCard parser. I am sure that has been done before :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [vCard Parsing different parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5729405/vcard-parsing-different-parameters)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try this parser : http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/vCardReader.aspx

I didn't test it but it seems to meet your needs